# Create correct loop output with python function

Tags: python

Could someone help me with following function:

```
def nagios_chart():
    alpha = [chr(item).upper() for item in range(ord('b'), ord('l')+1)]
    for idx, column in enumerate(alpha):
        print worksheet.write_column('column + 1', nagios_data[idx])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nagios_chart()
```

I need output like this:

```
worksheet.write_column('B1', nagios_data[0])
worksheet.write_column('C1', nagios_data[1])
worksheet.write_column('D1', nagios_data[2])
worksheet.write_column('E1', nagios_data[3])
worksheet.write_column('F1', nagios_data[4])
worksheet.write_column('G1', nagios_data[5])
worksheet.write_column('H1', nagios_data[6])
worksheet.write_column('I1', nagios_data[7])
worksheet.write_column('J1', nagios_data[8])
worksheet.write_column('K1', nagios_data[9])
worksheet.write_column('L1', nagios_data[10])
```

Comment: And what's the question you are asking?

Comment: Do you want to output the string `"worksheet.write_column('B1', nagios_data[0])"`, or do you want to call that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the `column` as a variable, remove it from the quotes so it isn't treated as a string literal. Then you can concatenate it with `'1'`.

```
def nagios_chart():
    alpha = [chr(item).upper() for item in range(ord('b'), ord('l')+1)]
    for idx, column in enumerate(alpha):
        print worksheet.write_column(column + '1', nagios_data[idx])
```